# Paying off all your credit cards but one before statement generation date : helpful?

Tags: united-states, credit-score, credit-history

Some people advocate paying off all your credit cards but one before statement generation date, **and** maintain a utilization of **no more than 9%** on that card

Here is my understanding and information I got so far:

1. Lenders officially recommend you not to carry more than 30% on your card
2. *However*, emperical data published on CreditKarma blog shows that people with **1 - 20% utilization tend to have** the highest credit scores
3. This implies that people following the 9% strategy **are effectively utilizing less than 9%** (depends on how many lines they have open)
4. I noticed a 'Max balance' cell on my credit report that **indeed reports the maximum amount that ever appeared on that card** statement **ever**.

My questions are:

1. Isn't this 'Max balance' cell on my credit report a long term
   information all my lenders have access to?

   Although this might not be too bad as the **context for lenders is
   missing**: I might have run a $1k Max balance on a $1.5k card (60%)
   that got upgraded to a $5k card (20%) later, but I never let the
   balance go over $1k again
2. How different is this strategy of paying off all your credit cards but one before statement generation date **from another strategy of charging your cards in such a manner that the net utilization is 9% or less** (No paying off any of your credit cards before statement generation. What I charge, gets reported in my monthly statement, and no card reports as 0 debit)?

Comment: The main question is: how useful is having the Max balance reported low?

Comment: Also, what if I followed an alternate strategy of charging my cards in such a manner that the net utilization is 9% or less (but not paying off any of the credit cards before statement generation. What I charge, gets reported in my monthly statement, and no card reports as 0 debit)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The credit utilization will impact your score each month. In an article I wrote titled "[too little debt?](http://www.joetaxpayer.com/too-little-debt/)" I described how by paying in full before the statement was cut, I took a hit for zero utilization. The next month it was back to normal. Paying in full each month. The "max utilized" is there, I agree, but doesn't impact the score from what I can tell. As you've noted, just keep below 20% (and not zero) and this portion of your score will be optimized.

Comment: The Max balance reported has a permanent memory as far as mu credit is concerned. How much of a memory does the utilization have? Does it effectively "reset" every month?

Comment: Also, what if I followed an alternate strategy of charging my cards in such a manner that the net utilization is 9% or less (but not paying off any of the credit cards before statement generation. What I charge, gets reported in my monthly statement, and no card reports as 0 debit)?

Comment: Yes. I got a 'C' for utilization for my zero month (according to Credit Karma) and right back to "A" the next month. Right to your second part. What appears as a statement balance is what counts. If one has need to charge more than 20% utilization, they should make partial payment before the bill is cut.

Comment: Is it safe to have all but one card report as 0 debt? What if the lender that issued the cards on which you have 0 debt cuts your credit for non-use? Can they do that?

Comment: It's safe as far as credit scoring. If I want to be sure a card isn't canceled, I use it a few times a year.